# FullCalendar how to detect last row event in a list view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to detect last row of the same event in a list view of fullcalendar.

I need this to show a different test ONLY for last row (when event is bigger than 1 day).

See pic example:[image]

This is the code i'm using but i don't know how to detect last row:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

        if ( view.type == "listYear" || view.type == "listMonth" ) {

          //i want to show it if last row of the event

          var duration = "<br>Durata: " + event.duration;

          // CODE TO IMPLEMENT
          //if ( NOT LAST ROW OF SAME EVENT ) {

            //duration = "";

          //}
          //END CODE TO IMPLEMENT

            var title = element.find( '.fc-list-item-title' );
            title.html( event.title + duration );

        }

    },
  events: [{
    title: 'Event 1',
    start: '2016-04-26 14:00',
    end: '2016-04-27 09:00',
  duration: '19 hours'
  },
{
    title: 'Event 2 (1 day)',
    start: '2016-04-26 14:00',
    end: '2016-04-26 17:00',
  duration: '3 hours'
  }]
```

jsfiddle to implement: http://jsfiddle.net/s7t2bc12/111/